# C3.js Tooltip was disabled after filling in between two lines (d3 svg area)

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I have encountered an issue with the C3.js tooltip not being triggered after I fill the areas between two lines using d3.svg.area. Fiddel: 
[Tooltip disabled by areas filling in between two lines](https://jsfiddle.net/Mandyzhu7/1xnc6y58/12/)

As we can see from the example, when we hover to the point outside the area, the tooltip will show up; but when we move to the point inside the area, nothing will be shown. I assume that the d3.svg.area has been impacting the C3.js tooltip behaviour, but what/where exactly? Any one got ideas about this?

I also tried to set the z-index of the area to be smaller than the line and circles, but it does not help at all.
I added the code below and set breakpoint, and it was not hit when hovering to the first point.

```
tooltip: {
format: {
        title: function(d) { 
    console.log(d); 
            return d; 
        },  
} }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: the first point does not have tooltip anymore!!]

Comment: You have to append the area before the elements that get the mouse events: https://jsfiddle.net/7scyhax7/ There is **no** z-index in an SVG: only the **order** matters.

Comment: aha...I see. Thank you very much for the explanation and help.

Comment: But the filling color is gone, how can I still keep the colors between the two lines? Sorry for bothering again.

Comment: The problem was that the area was not really appended. Here is the working version: https://jsfiddle.net/Mandyzhu7/7scyhax7/1/.